# Mysql query result not bigger than one month from the current date

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a database which has a field `date` inside it which has the following format: `2013-09-03` for example. I am making a mysql query which is displaying results from this database but I would like to modify it this way so it will display only the results which data is not more than 31 days from today or one month , where today must me the date of today get from the server, here is the query so far: if

```
(!$result = mysqli_query($con,
 "SELECT id, title, date, date_until, content FROM dashboard WHERE city = 'VC' AND type = 'class' AND  status = '1'"))
```

for example if today is first of january the results which the query should show are which have date no bigger than 1 oF february.

any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`(!$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, title, date, date_until, content FROM dashboard WHERE city = 'VC' AND type = 'class' AND  status = '1' AND DATEDIFF(date, NOW()) <= 31"));`

However, it would be better to pre-calculate the cutoff date to avoid MYSQL having to do the DATEDIFF for all rows, so something like:

`$cutoff = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+31 day");
(!$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, title, date, date_until, content FROM dashboard WHERE city = 'VC' AND type = 'class' AND  status = '1' AND date <= '$cutoff'"));`

Comment: Yields a correct result set, but using a function on the `date` column defeats the use of any index for this search.

Comment: Ive tryed both solutions but the result greater than 31 days or a month are still getting inside the query

Comment: John, can you echo $cutoff to make sure it is as expected (a date 31 days from now), and post the table schema so we can check the format of the date column please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using date arithmetic

```
 WHERE ...
   AND date <= TODAY() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: it gives me an error on TODAY I changed it with NOW but still the results are not limited by date

Comment: Please tell us your table definition.  Does your `date` column have the `DATETIME` date type?

Comment: the type is only: date of the column